# Angular Input string is undefined

Tags: angular, angular-material

In this component i am trying to pass an input string named "propertyName" in order to display a property of an object.

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="propertyName" style="width: 500px;" class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
  <mat-label >{{label}}</mat-label>
  <input  [disabled]="disableInput" type="text" matInput (input)="filter($event)" [formControl]="formControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" >
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn" >
    <mat-option *ngFor="let elemento of dataToFilter " (click)="onSelection.emit(elemento)" [value]="elemento">
    {{decapitalize(elemento[propertyName])}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dropdown-autocomplete',
  templateUrl: './dropdown-autocomplete.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dropdown-autocomplete.component.css']
})
export class DropdownAutocompleteComponent {

  @Input() label? : string;
  @Input() data! : any[];
  @Input() formControl!: FormControl;
  @Input() propertyName!: string;
  @Input() disableInput!: boolean;
  @Output() onSelection: any = new EventEmitter<any>()

  dataToFilter?: any[] = [];
  selected = '';
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataToFilter = this.data;
    // if (this.defaultValue) {
    //   this.selected = this.defaultValue;
    // }
  }

  filter(inputString : any) {
    const filterValue = inputString.target.value.toLowerCase();
    this.dataToFilter = this.data.filter(option => option[this.propertyName].toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)
    // || option.aliasEntes[0]?.nomeAlternativo.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)
    );
  }

  decapitalize(str: string) {
    return str.replace(/(^\w|\s\w)(\S*)/g, (_,m1,m2) => m1.toUpperCase()+m2.toLowerCase())
  }

  displayFn(elem: any) {
    if (elem && this.propertyName) {
      console.log(this.propertyName);
      return elem[this.propertyName];
    }
    return '';
  }
}
```

Other component calling it:

```
      <app-dropdown-autocomplete
        [propertyName]="'nome'"
        [label]="'Ente'"
        [data]="entiToFilter"
        [formControl]="formControl"
        [disableInput]="disableInput"
        (onSelection)="selectedEnte = $event"
      >
```

As you can see, i am passing the string as [propertyName]="'nome'" , but in the code it results being undefined, even if declared as @Input() propertyName!: string;

I even tried setting up a *ngIf at the start of the component, and it gets rendered, but the property still remains undefined

Comment: i dont see any issue with your code, can you share a minimal stackblitz reproduction

Comment: Is the `label` string value coming in as expected or does it have an issue too? Are you sure that the single quotes are the real single quotes, not the language-specific characters?

Comment: You could try passing only the propertyName to your child component in order to be sure that this variable causes the problem